# How to get a pandas df from a json API response

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

so I have this JSON response from an API call

```py
{ "search": { "entry": [
{ "dn": "cn=SlackIntegration-test1,ou=metadata,ou=ibmgroups,o=ibm.com",
"attribute": [
{ "name": "admin", "value": [ "uid=052355781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] },
{ "name": "owner", "value": [ "uid=052355781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] }]
},
{ "dn": "cn=SlackIntegration-test2,ou=metadata,ou=ibmgroups,o=ibm.com",
"attribute": [
{ "name": "admin", "value": [ "uid=001753781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] },
{ "name": "owner", "value": [ "uid=052355781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] }]
},
{ "dn": "cn=SlackIntegration-pidtest,ou=metadata,ou=ibmgroups,o=ibm.com",
"attribute": [
{ "name": "admin", "value": [ "uid=000326781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] },
{ "name": "owner", "value": [ "uid=052355781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] }]
},
{ "dn": "cn=SlackIntegration-APItest,ou=metadata,ou=ibmgroups,o=ibm.com",
"attribute": [
{ "name": "owner", "value": [ "uid=052355781,c=mx,ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com" ] }]
}
],
"return": {
"code": 0,
"message": "Success",
"count": 4
}
} }
```

And I'm expecting to have a df like this

| index | cn | admin | owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SlackIntegration-test1 | 052355781 | 052355781 |
| 1 | SlackIntegration-test2 | 001753781 | 052355781 |
| 2 | SlackIntegration-pidtest | 000326781 | 052355781 |
| 3 | SlackIntegration-APItest |  | 052355781 |

I have not been able to normalize the json or maybe how to iterate in the json to get something like that, so far I have this code but it only returns this.

```py
def get_channel_info():

    LOGGER.info("Getting channel name")
    url = 'http://bluepages.ibm.com/BpHttpApisv3/slaphapi?ou=metadata,ou=ibmgroups,o=ibm.com/\
          (cn=slack*).list,base/byjson?*cn&owner&admin'
    # request to API
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        if requests.get.status_code == 429:
            LOGGER.warning("Request limit reached. Waiting 4 minutes and attempting request again.")
            time.sleep(240)
            res = requests.get(url)
        else:
            LOGGER.error('Request error occurred. HTTP Status:{:0}'.format(requests.get.status_code))
            raise
    if res.status_code == 200:
        json_res = res.json()
        json_res = json_res['search']['entry']
        for row in json_res:
            data = json_res[int(json_res.index(row))]['attribute']
            df_band = pd.DataFrame(data)

    return df_band
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `d` contains the dictionary from the question, you can use this example:

```py
data = []
for e in d["search"]["entry"]:
    data.append(
        {
            "cn": e["dn"].split(",")[0].split("=")[-1],
            **{
                a["name"]: a["value"][0].split(",")[0].split("=")[-1]
                for a in e["attribute"]
            },
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data).fillna("")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         cn      admin      owner
0    SlackIntegration-test1  052355781  052355781
1    SlackIntegration-test2  001753781  052355781
2  SlackIntegration-pidtest  000326781  052355781
3  SlackIntegration-APItest             052355781
```

Comment: Yeap just what I was looking for, thank you!!